# What do I need to install on a Windows Server 2012 64-bit box to deploy an ASP.NET MVC project under IIS using DNX SDK version 1.0.0-beta8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, iis-8

I have published a website in VS2015 built using ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 and configured it in IIS on a different server but I am getting an HTTP404 error when I try to Browse the application. The deployment from VS2015 uses DNX SDK version 1.0.0-beta8. Do I need to install anything else on the IIS server in order to get this to work does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following this guide I was able to do the installation: Really helpful guide: [http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html][1]